# Forwarding a call from active Twilio Call

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twilio

I have a Angular.JS based browser soft phone successfully initiating phone calls through the browser.  The one initiating through the browser is the operator and the person answering is the caller.

I would like the operator to be able to transfer the caller to another line at some point in the call.

I am able to modify the active call with the code below, which reveals TWIML for an automated recording system.  However, when the operator tries to redirect, its the operator who gets sent to the service and the caller is just hung up on.

Any Advice...first Twilio project.

```
client.calls(callSid).update({
url: "http://callcenter-test.herokuapp.com/twiml/tomachine/" + phone,
method: "POST",
Called: phone,
to: phone,
from: phone,
}, function(err, call) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
console.log('call = '+ call);
});
```

The TWIML revealed at the URL above:

http://twimlbin.com/94a65384

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your problem here is that you are redirecting the wrong leg of the call. There is a call Sid for the side of the call between the operator and Twilio and a different Sid for the caller and Twilio. You need to save the Sid of the call made to the caller and then use that in the update function.